# Mysql left join with another table with passed variable

Tags: php, mysql, join, subquery, left-join

I have 2 tables named `projects` and `tracklines`
Every project can have multiple tracklines.

I have an SQL statement that will loop through my projects, but I want to be able to JOIN the trackline table with only 1 row. What I want to do is get all tracklines that are part of a project, order them based on more than one field and do a LIMIT 1 on it so that I have one trackline which I'm joining with my project.

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT Project.* FROM `project` AS `Project`
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT *
    FROM `trackline`
    WHERE `trk_deleted` = '0'
    ORDER BY `trk_state`, `trk_status`
    LIMIT 1
) t ON t.`trk_project` = `prj_id`
ORDER BY `prj_name`
```

The problem is that I am not getting the `trk_state` and `trk_status` values in my outer query.

I was thinking that my subquery could have WHERE `trk_project` = `prd_id` but I am not sure how to get that to happen.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pull values from that derived table as well:

```
SELECT Project.*, t.*
FROM ...
```

right now it's retrieving ONLY the fields from the Project table.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I have done that already even though my code didn't provide it. The main problem I'm having is that if I take away the "LEFT" from the join, no result set is returned meaning that no joins were being done. I figure I have something wrong with the logic I'm using to JOIN the 2 tables.

Comment: making it just a `JOIN` makes it a default `INNER JOIN`, where'd you get results only if there's a matching record on both sides of the query - which means your `ON` clause in the join isn't working right.

Comment: Yea, I understand the difference between JOINS and LEFT JOINS. If I were to do a LEFT JOIN without using the subquery, I will get results. I'm guessing the method I'm using is what is causing the join not to work.

Comment: Is that limit necessary in the subquery? That causes it to return only a single record to be joined on. Most likely you don't have any records in the project table that match that one single record, so the inner join produces nothing.

Comment: Is there some way I can bring the condition trk_project = prj_id into the subquery. I want the subquery to return a maximum of 1 result. The subquery doesn't like `prj_id`

Comment: Not really: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/530381/mysql-correlated-subquery-in-join-syntax