# Where clause inside joined select

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to accommodate a similar solution to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/530381/mysql-correlated-subquery-in-join-syntax) - what I have is a SELECT query inside a JOIN, and the problem is that the query runs at full for all rows (I'm talking 60,000 rows per table - and it runs on 3 tables!).

So what I want to do, is add a WHERE clause to the SELECTs inside the JOIN.
But, I can't access the outer SELECT and get the proper WHERE condition I need.
The query I'm **attempting** is here:

```
SELECT  c.compete_id AS id,
      s.id AS store_id,
      c.enabled AS enabled,
      s.store_name AS store_name,
      s.store_url AS store_url,
      c.verified AS verified,
      r.rating_total AS rating,
      r.positive_percent AS percent,
      r.type AS type
FROM compete_settings c
LEFT JOIN stores s
    ON c.compete_id = s.id
LEFT JOIN (
    (SELECT store_id, rating_total, positive_percent, 'ebay' AS type FROM ebay_sellers WHERE store_id = c.compete_id)
    UNION
    (SELECT store_id, rating_total, positive_percent, 'amazon' AS type FROM amazon_sellers WHERE store_id = c.compete_id)
    UNION
    (SELECT store_id, CASE WHEN rank = 0 THEN NULL ELSE (200000 - rank) END AS rating_total, '100' as positive_percent, 'alexa' AS type FROM alexa_ratings WHERE store_id = c.compete_id)
) AS r
ON c.compete_id = r.store_id
    WHERE c.store_id = :store_id
```

Note, `:store_id` is a variable bound through the framework - let's imagine it's the number `12345`.

How can I do this? Any ideas?

Comment: Just omit the `WHERE story_id = c.store_id` from the subquery. It is being used as a joinfield on the `r` union, so the match will take place at the outer level. BTW: the `union`s should/could be `union all`s.

Comment: What wildplasser said:  rely on your join condition for r.  Separately, I've sometimes had datatype troubles in UNIONs with hardwired values.  Something like "CAST('ebay' AS VARCHAR(50)) AS type" may prevent the type column from coming out too short for the other values.  Though I see this problem more often with bit/integer types.

Comment: @wildplasser but it fetches the whole set of rows beforehand, which is what I want to avoid. It's running the query and retrieving 90,000 rows together, only to omit 95% of them at the best case, 99.5% on the worse case.

Comment: This depends on the query generator/optimiser + the key structure + the statistics + the DBMS platform (mysql might be a bit awkward) But, since the subclause is anchored anyway, you could always rewrite it to `(SELECT store_id, rating_total, positive_percent, 'ebay' AS type FROM ebay_sellers WHERE store_id = :store_id)`, and similar for the other legs of the UNION.

Comment: The `:store_id` isn't the right condition - or I wouldn't have this problem; I need `compete_id` which is a bit different... Anyways we came up with a different solution, I'll post it in a few minutes. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

We ended up going witha  different approach - we just JOINed everything and only selected the right columns with a CASE. Here's the final query:

```
SELECT  c.id AS id,
      s.id AS store_id,
      c.enabled AS enabled,
      s.store_name AS store_name,
      s.store_url AS store_url,
      c.verified AS verified,
      (CASE WHEN eb.rating_total IS NOT NULL THEN eb.rating_total
            WHEN am.rating_total IS NOT NULL THEN am.rating_total
            WHEN ax.rank IS NOT NULL THEN ax.rank
      END) AS rating,
      (CASE WHEN eb.positive_percent IS NOT NULL THEN eb.positive_percent
            WHEN am.positive_percent IS NOT NULL THEN am.positive_percent
            WHEN ax.rank IS NOT NULL THEN '100'
      END) AS percent,
      (CASE WHEN eb.positive_percent IS NOT NULL THEN 'ebay'
            WHEN am.positive_percent IS NOT NULL THEN 'amazon'
            WHEN ax.rank IS NOT NULL THEN 'alexa'
      END) AS type
FROM compete_settings c
LEFT JOIN stores s
  ON c.compete_id = s.id
LEFT JOIN ebay_sellers eb ON c.compete_id = eb.store_id
LEFT JOIN amazon_sellers am ON c.compete_id = am.store_id
LEFT JOIN alexa_ratings ax ON c.compete_id = ax.store_id
WHERE c.store_id = :store_id
```